# Women's (men's) or female (male)?

Tags: noun-phrases

I was teaching a student the other day when we began talking about women's sports/female sports. She then asked can we say is that a "female" handbag or a women's handbag. I suppose a "female" handbag kind of makes grammatical sense but we'd just never say it. Is there a rule about this?

Comment: *Female handbag* collides with *female animal*. Since handbags don't have a sex, the former isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

*Female* as an adjective denotes *female characteristics*. The handbag itself is not female, nor does it have female characteristics. The idiomatic way to describe such an item is "*a women's handbag*".

The same is true of sports - we would normally say *women's sports* because the sports themselves are not female; however, it would be correct to say "*a female athlete*" if the athlete *is* female.

Comment: We have male and female toilets in the UK.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm in the UK, and they are generally described as "ladies' toilets" and "gentlemen's toilets". If the doors are labelled simply "MALE" and "FEMALE" that is an example of *signage* which does not have to follow the rules of grammar any more than a road sign that says "STOP".

Comment: The Government department that employs me calls them 'male toilet' and 'female toilet' on the plans of our building.

Comment: "Lapee is an industrial-standard **female urinal** for festivals and outdoor events that allows people to pee sitting down quickly and safely." -advertisement, "the disturbing incident in a Los Angeles Denny’s restaurant in May 2018, where a former US Republican candidate filmed herself abusing a transgender woman using a **female toilet** as she was evicted by security." - The Guardian "There are **female toilet facilities** available" - National Rail (about Wimbledon Station)

Comment: "**female toilet** - located in the second Zoology building, down the left corridor. It is located on the right side of the corridor." University of Crawley (Western Australia), "Man, 30, charged for entering **female toilet** to film women on Christmas night" - Singapore Today, 'In New Zealand, they don’t hesitate to use the word “female.” The signs for public rest rooms there (and in Australia) read, unabashedly, **“Female Toilet”** and **“Male Toilet.”**- the New Yorker

Comment: "I'm in the UK, and they are generally described as "ladies' toilets" and "gentlemen's toilets". Not any more.